# Opening a "closed" port

Tags: linux, networking, suse, port

I am trying to set up a SAP System on SUSE Enterprise, but I'm having trouble connecting to the server.
I added multiple ports to the public section of the firewall and with most of them I am able to reach the server through that port.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

From the outside I am now able to the test the connection to my server, for example from a windows client succesfully via

```
test-connection -computername [IPADDRESS] -port 8000
```

But for the port 3200 this doesnt work.

When I use nmap I get the following result:

```
nmap -p 3200 [IPADDRESS]

PORT      STATE   SERVICE

3200/tcp  closed  tick-port
```

I already tried commenting the ports out from `/etc/services` but the result stays the same.

How can I "open" this port?

Comment: is something listening on port 3200? `netstat -putan`

Comment: if you do `lsof -ni :3200` is anything running on that port.
Can you connect to port 3200 locally

Comment: `netstat -putan` is not working for, can't get netstat to run on SUSE.

Comment: `lsof -ni :3200` doesn't return anything in the terminal

Comment: Well in that case, nothing is listening on that port. So that's why you cannot access it from the outside. Start the service which should listen on port 3200 and try again

Comment: If you can't run `netstat` you can also try `ss` like `ss -tunlp`, if you don't get anything returned by `lsof -ni :3200` then it doesn't seem to be a process running and listening on that port. check if the sap service is running `systemct status name_of_sap_service`

Comment: To summarize, it's probably not a networking problem, but an application problem.

Comment: Indeed I am trying to reach a SAP System through that port and `ss -tulp | grep LISTEN` doesn't return any service with that port.
Now i need to find out, which service should be listening to that port.

Comment: try ss -ltunap | grep 3200 what do you get with this command

Comment: Unfortunately nothing

Answer (score -2):

Found the missing service. When I started it, port was listened to.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: This answer seems to lack information about how the service was identified and started.